# App Store Connect can't add builds to external testers or submit build

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect

I'm using TestFlight and trying to submit my build so that the external testers can test the app , but the problem is there is no option appear to me to submit builds , and no option to delete old builds,
I have two builds with status "Missing Compliance" and one build "Ready to Submit"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0SbA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have the necessary role permission to manage TestFlight builds as well as External Testers.

[image: App Store Connect Roles]

[Apple Store Connect Roles](https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/)